# how to fix List is not subtype of string

Tags: flutter, dart

so i've got values that im trying to insert into my db , but everytime i try to add them i get the the error :

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

below is code where my list values are stored , essentially the values are collected from a dyanmic textfields then further mapped into the lists -

```
List<TextEditingController> dataType = [];
  List<TextEditingController> addOn = [];
  List<TextEditingController> priceType = [];

  List<String> filteredDataTypes =
        dataType.map((controller) => controller.text).toList();

    List<String> filteredPriceType =
        priceType.map((controller) => controller.text).toList();

    List<String> filteredAddOn =
        addOn.map((controller) => controller.text).toList();
```

this is where or how im trying to model the data into my db :

```
  add(dataModel dataModel) async {
        await ref.read(dataProvider).addData(dataModel).then((success) {});
      }
    
     DataModel dataModel = DataModel(
                  ID: '',
                  dataTypes: filteredDataTypes,
                  price: filteredPriceType,
                  addOn: filteredAddOn,
                );
                add(dataModel);     

the code below is code from the controller that sends the data to the db together with the data model for context's sake :

final dataProvider = Provider((ref) => dataController());

class dataController {

  Future<String> addData(DataModel dataModel) async {
    try {final res =
        await http.post(Uri.parse(API.addData), body: dataModel.toJsonAdd());

      print("Add res${res.body}");
      return res.body;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw Exception('something went wrong');
    }
  }

class DataModel {
  String ID;
  List<String> dataType;
  List<String> price;
  List<String> addOn;
  DataModel({
    required this.ID, 
    required this.dataType,
    required this.price,
    required this.addOn,
  });

  factory dataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      ID: json['ID'] ?? '' ,
      dataTypes:  List<String>.from(json['dataType']??'') , 
      price:  List<String>.from(json['price']??'') ,
      addOn:  List<String>.from(json['addOn']??'') ,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJsonAdd() => {
        "mealID":mealID,
        "dataTypes": dataTypes,
        "price": price,
        "addOn": mealAddOn,
      };
}
```